# How to stop the screeching noise that comes from buzzer?

Tags: arduino-uno, sound, piezo, buzzer

> I use sfm-27 dc 3-24v Buzzer. It sounds fine if i close the buzzer using my palm but if i doesn't close it, it will make a screeching noise. I play melody using the buzzer so the sound is important. This is the code that i use.

```
    const int buzzer = 4; //Define pin 13, can use other PWM pins  (5,6 or 9)
                       //Note pins 3 and 11 can't be used when using the tone function in Arduino Uno
const int songspeed = 1.5; //Change to 2 for a slower version of the song, the bigger the number the slower the song
//*****************************************
#define NOTE_C4  262   //Defining note frequency
#define NOTE_D4  294
#define NOTE_E4  330
#define NOTE_F4  349
#define NOTE_G4  392
#define NOTE_A4  440
#define NOTE_B4  494
#define NOTE_C5  523
#define NOTE_D5  587
#define NOTE_E5  659
#define NOTE_F5  698
#define NOTE_G5  784
#define NOTE_A5  880
#define NOTE_B5  988
//*****************************************
int notes[] = {       //Note of the song, 0 is a rest/pulse
   NOTE_E4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A4, 0, 
   NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_C5, 0, 
   NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_B4, 0,
   NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, 0,

   NOTE_E4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A4, 0, 
   NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_C5, 0, 
   NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_B4, 0,
   NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, 0,

   NOTE_E4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A4, 0, 
   NOTE_A4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_D5, 0, 
   NOTE_D5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_F5, NOTE_F5, 0,
   NOTE_E5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_A4, 0,

   NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_C5, 0, 
   NOTE_D5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_A4, 0, 
   NOTE_A4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_B4, 0,
   NOTE_C5, NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, 0,

   NOTE_A4, NOTE_A4, 
   //Repeat of first part
   NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_C5, 0, 
   NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_B4, 0,
   NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, 0,

   NOTE_E4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A4, 0, 
   NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_C5, 0, 
   NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_B4, 0,
   NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, 0,

   NOTE_E4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_A4, 0, 
   NOTE_A4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_D5, 0, 
   NOTE_D5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_F5, NOTE_F5, 0,
   NOTE_E5, NOTE_D5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_A4, 0,

   NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_C5, 0, 
   NOTE_D5, NOTE_E5, NOTE_A4, 0, 
   NOTE_A4, NOTE_C5, NOTE_B4, NOTE_B4, 0,
   NOTE_C5, NOTE_A4, NOTE_B4, 0,
   //End of Repeat

   NOTE_E5, 0, 0, NOTE_F5, 0, 0,
   NOTE_E5, NOTE_E5, 0, NOTE_G5, 0, NOTE_E5, NOTE_D5, 0, 0,
   NOTE_D5, 0, 0, NOTE_C5, 0, 0,
   NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, 0, NOTE_B4, 0, NOTE_A4,

   NOTE_E5, 0, 0, NOTE_F5, 0, 0,
   NOTE_E5, NOTE_E5, 0, NOTE_G5, 0, NOTE_E5, NOTE_D5, 0, 0,
   NOTE_D5, 0, 0, NOTE_C5, 0, 0,
   NOTE_B4, NOTE_C5, 0, NOTE_B4, 0, NOTE_A4
};
//*****************************************
int duration[] = {         //duration of each note (in ms) Quarter Note is set to 250 ms
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125, 
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125,
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125,
  125, 125, 375, 125, 

  125, 125, 250, 125, 125, 
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125,
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125,
  125, 125, 375, 125, 

  125, 125, 250, 125, 125, 
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125,
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125,
  125, 125, 125, 250, 125,

  125, 125, 250, 125, 125, 
  250, 125, 250, 125, 
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125,
  125, 125, 375, 375,

  250, 125,
  //Rpeat of First Part
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125,
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125,
  125, 125, 375, 125, 

  125, 125, 250, 125, 125, 
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125,
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125,
  125, 125, 375, 125, 

  125, 125, 250, 125, 125, 
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125,
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125,
  125, 125, 125, 250, 125,

  125, 125, 250, 125, 125, 
  250, 125, 250, 125, 
  125, 125, 250, 125, 125,
  125, 125, 375, 375,
  //End of Repeat

  250, 125, 375, 250, 125, 375,
  125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 375,
  250, 125, 375, 250, 125, 375,
  125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 500,

  250, 125, 375, 250, 125, 375,
  125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 375,
  250, 125, 375, 250, 125, 375,
  125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 500
};

void setup() {
  for (int i=0;i<203;i++){              //203 is the total number of music notes in the song
  int wait = duration[i] * songspeed;
  tone(buzzer,notes[i],wait);          //tone(pin,frequency,duration)
  delay(wait);}                        //delay is used so it doesn't go to the next loop before tone is finished playing
  //You can click reset on Arduino to replay the song
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: you probaby cannot ... most likely the buzzer is not for playing music ... apply DC voltage and it buzzes ... apply AC voltage and you hear rhe buzz modulated at the frequency of the voltage

Comment: ok thank you so much.